# Mysql query for listing field values from one table to another

Tags: mysql, subquery, opencart

I have the following mysql query:

```
  SELECT order_id, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS customer, shipping_code, total, currency_code, currency_value, date_added, date_modified FROM oc_order` o LEFT JOIN (select komercijalista from oc_customer (order.customer_id = customer.customer_id))
```

I am trying to list values from `komercijalista` field (which belongs to `oc_customer` table) in `oc_order` table. I am trying to connect them by `customer_id` which both have, but I am failing at left join. Any suggestions, please? Apart from learning mysql better, which I am already trying to do and this is where I need your help. Thanx.

Comment: Help us help you - please share the tables structures, some sample data and the result you're trying to get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx to @p.ganesh, I managed to figure out how to write the query. In case someone needs this, here is the solution:

```
SELECT order_id, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS customer, shipping_code, total, currency_code, currency_value, date_added, date_modified FROM oc_order` o LEFT JOIN (select komercijalista from oc_customer (order.customer_id = customer.customer_id))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT o.order_id, CONCAT(o.firstname, ' ', o.lastname) AS customer, o.shipping_code, o.total, o.currency_code, o.currency_value, o.date_added, o.date_modified ,b.komercijalista FROM `oc_order` o left join (select komercijalista from oc_customer) b on o.order_id = b.customer.order_id
```

try this

Comment: Hi @p.ganesh I get errors with this query "unknown column o.order_id" and for  all other columns  with prefix  o and b. I do not know how to use left join with my current query. If left join is the right thing to use.

Comment: In which table does order_id columns exists,does order _id column exists in oc_order table or not ,please provide some data ,now again copy that query and run

Comment: order_id exists in both tables (table oc_customer and table oc_order). I have komercijalista field in oc_customer only, which is why i need to join two tables in order to display komercijalista field values.

Comment: CORRECTION: customer_id is in both oc_customer table and oc_order table. My bad, sorry! I will correct my question.

Comment: I changed to customer_id in query,but i get this error - Unknown column 'b.customer_id' in 'on clause'.

Comment: I got it right with your help @p.ganesh. Thank you for suggestion, it was very helpful.